# question about Factory Girl syntax for passing an option to a trait

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I am taking over a project that has a question / answer section. I am adding a syndication feature and would like to have a relationship where a question has_one: syndicatable_question.

For my factrory, I have an API like `sq = FactoryGirl.create(:question, :with_syndication )` for the simple case and would like something like `sq = FactoryGirl.create(:question, :with_syndication(syndicatable_location_id: 345))` but this doesn't work. How could I pass an option / argument  for a trait? What changes would I need to make to the factory?

My factory currently looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question, class: Content::Question do
    specialty_id 2
    subject { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    body { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    location_id 24005

    trait :with_syndication do
      after(:create) do |q, options|
        create(:syndicatable_question, question_id: q.id, syndicatable_location_id: q.location_id)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `transient` block to your trait

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :question, class: Content::Question do
    specialty_id 2
    subject { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
    body { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
    location_id 24005

    transient do
      syndicatable_location_id 24005
    end

    trait :with_syndication do
      after(:create) do |q, options|
        create(:syndicatable_question, question_id: q.id, syndicatable_location_id: options.syndicatable_location_id)
      end
    end
  end
end


FactoryGirl.create(:question, :with_syndication, syndicatable_location_id: 345)
```

Transient Attributes
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Traits

Comment: is there a way to make location_id a variable in transient? that dupe is so ugly

Comment: Static and dynamic attributes can be created as transient attributes. Transient attributes will be ignored within attributes_for and won't be set on the model, even if the attribute exists or you attempt to override it. (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Transient_Attributes)

But, If you need to assign location_id value from `question` you don't need `transient` block.

after(:create)
`create(:syndicatable_question, question_id: q.id, syndicatable_location_id: q.location_id)`
  

`FactoryGirl.create(:question, :with_syndication)`